# Load values from a list in Red language

Tags: user-interface, variable-assignment, rebol, red

I am trying following code to read values from a list to be put into field elements which are also placed in another list:

```
Red [needs: view]

view [
    text "N1:"
    ff: field ""
    text "N2:"
    gg: field ""

    do [fldlist: [ff gg] 
        vv: 5  ww: 10
        varlist: [vv ww]   ]

    button "Click" [
        repeat i (length? varlist) 
            [to-set-path to-word fldlist/i/text:  varlist/:i]  ] ]
```

However, it is not working. The error is:

```
*** Script Error: path fldlist/i/text: is not valid for none! type
*** Where: set-path
*** Stack: view do-events do-actor do-safe to-set-path to-word
```

I also tried `:i` `(i)` and `(:i)` instead of just `i` but it is not working. Where is the problem and how can it be solved? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
 button "Click" [
    repeat i (length? varlist)   [
        tmp: get fldlist/:i
        tmp/text:  form get varlist/:i
    ]  
]
```

I think, you should start to read some documentation about the concepts of  [Red](http://www.red-lang.org/p/documentation.html) and [Rebol](http://www.rebol.com/docs.html) and/or just debug the code in the console.

**Update**

I have to concede, that in this regards Red does not behave as I was expecting from Rebol experience. But I got another tricky solution without temporary words.

```
button "Click" [
    repeat i (length? varlist) [
        set first find words-of get fldlist/:i  'text form get varlist/:i
    ]  
]
```

Answer (score 1):

This answer uses a map to coalesce the values you're looking to apply, cycles through the value names and compares them to field names with a corresponding `extra` value, setting them to that value.

```
values: #(foo: 5 bar: 10)
fields: #()

ui: layout [
    text "N1:"
    field 100 extra 'foo
    text "N2:"
    field 100 extra 'bar

    button "Click" [
        foreach word intersect words-of values words-of fields [
            fields/:word/text: form values/:word
        ]
    ]
]

foreach kid ui/pane [
    if kid/extra [
        put fields kid/extra kid
    ]
]

view ui
```

I would suggest however that the second example in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46354461/292969) is a better approach.