# Use strings to create words and paths in Red language

Tags: user-interface, variable-assignment, rebol, red

I have strings in a `namelist`, that correspond to variables as well as field names in the application.

The function should read strings from namelist, add an 'f' to get field_names, and then put variable values in corresponding fields.

I tried following code, that does not give any error, but also does not work:

```
namelist: ["var1" "var2"]
var1: 5
var2: 10

process: [
    repeat i length? namelist [
        (to-set-path compose rejoin [namelist/:i "f/text"] (to-word namelist/:i))
    ]
]

lay: layout [ 
    text "Values to appear here: "
    var1f: field "a"
    var2f: field "b"

    button "Click" [do process]
]

view lay
```

Comment: Your code could be structured better so it's easier to understand. It would help to separate the different parts and use that as a template in all the code you submit

Comment: It does seem like you're going out of your way to do something that's not quite clear. What is your goal here?—to use `var1` and `var2` as defaults for the fields with the 'Click' button for resetting, or do you intend to sync the fields with `var1` and `var2`? It's not really clear from your naming choices what your intent is.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As a general point: it is easy to turn strings into WORD!s *(e.g. `to-word "foo"`)*.  However, it can be tough to magically make that WORD! reference be bound to "the variable you meant".  The wily reasons for this have to do with the fact that there *is no scope*.  See:

[Is there a overall explanation about definitional scoping in Rebol and Red](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21964110/is-there-a-overall-explanation-about-definitional-scoping-in-rebol-and-red)

So what you are trying to do is going to be a little dodgy regardless.  There are better ways.  But to try to avoid un-asking the question, I'll explain what's happening here and how to fix it in the style you were attempting.

## corrected version is for instructional purposes only.  please do this another way.

> `compose rejoin [namelist/:i "f/text"]`

REJOIN is applied to blocks, and merges the contents, with a result type *loosely* based on the first element.  *(It's a [questionable operation](https://forum.rebol.info/t/rejoin-ugliness-and-the-usefulness-of-tests/248), but historically popular in Rebol code.)*

Since `namelist/:i` is a string, your REJOIN will produce a string...and this string will wind up being passed to COMPOSE.  But COMPOSE is meant to be applied to BLOCK!s...and searches for parenthesized groups *inside* of it, evaluating them while leaving the rest of the code alone.  It's a kind of templating system for blocks, with no effect on other kinds of input...so you'll get the same string out.

TO-SET-PATH is thus being fed a STRING! *(e.g. "var1f/text")*.  I didn't even know that path conversion accepted strings.  I find the behavior of this operation to be puzzling, because it apparently LOADs the string and then makes it the singular element of a length 1 SET-PATH!.

```
>> p: to-set-path "foo/bar"
== foo/bar: ;-- huh? really, did that work?

>> type? p
== set-path! ;-- ok, good, I guess.

>> length? p
== 1 ;-- wait, what?

>> type? first p
== path! ;-- a PATH! inside a SET-PATH!...?

>> length? first p
== 2

>> type? first first p
== word!

>> foo: 10
>> get first first p
== 10 ;-- well, at least it's bound
```

That's not making the kind of SET-PATH! you want; you want a SET-PATH! with 2 WORD! elements.  Converting a BLOCK! to a SET-PATH! would be a way of doing this.

```
to-set-path compose [(load rejoin [namelist/:i "f"]) text]
```

Now we see COMPOSE being used correctly, where it will run the evaluation inside the parentheses and leave the `text` word alone.  This produces a block with 2 elements in it, which is easily converted to a SET-PATH!.  I'm using LOAD instead of TO-WORD to take care of some of the "magic" of connecting to an actual variable that plain word conversion would not do.  But it's just a workaround--not a sure thing, and won't always be the answer to the problem.

But producing a SET-PATH! doesn't mean it runs.  If I say:

```
s: to-set-word "x"
probe type? s
```

No SET-WORD! is executed, it's merely generated.  And in this case, stored in the variable s.  But if I hadn't stored it in a variable, the evaluation product would have just been thrown out...the way 2 is simply thrown out if I write `1 + 1 print "hi"`.  To execute the SET-PATH!, you need to put it in a context where it will be composed into source and evaluated.

*(Note: Ren-C has a [primitive called EVAL](https://forum.rebol.info/t/meet-the-eval-native/311) which can do this on the fly, e.g. `eval (quote x:) 10` will assign 10 to x.)*

But in Red you'll need to do something like this:

```
namelist: ["var1" "var2"]
var1: 5
var2: 10

process: [
    repeat i length? namelist [
        do probe compose [
            (to-set-path compose [(load rejoin [namelist/:i "f"]) text])
            to-string
            (load namelist/:i)
        ]
    ]
]

lay: layout [ 
    text "Values to appear here: "
    var1f: field "a"
    var2f: field "b"

    button "Click" [do process]
]

view lay
```

Now your outer COMPOSE is building an 3-element block, where the first element will be a SET-PATH!, the second a WORD! that was literally left alone to convert your integer to a string, and the third a WORD! that will be evaluated to the relevant integer.  The DO of that block will have the assignment effect.

I changed your `to-word namelist/:i` to `load namelist/:i`.  Again, for the reason I mentioned...TO-WORD alone doesn't put on a "binding".

I left a PROBE in there so you could see what is built and executed:

```
[var1f/text: to-string var1]
[var2f/text: to-string var2]
```

PROBE is a very helpful tool, which outputs its argument but also passes it through.  You can insert it at various points in your code to get a better understanding of what's going on.

*(Note: If you're wondering why I don't suggest writing a narrow EVAL-2 helper operation that only works for SET-PATH!, it's because such a thing exists with a better name. It's called SET. Try `set (quote x:) 10` then `print x`. In fact, variants of this is how you'd actually want to do things... `obj: make object! [a: 10]` then `set (in obj 'a) 20` then `print obj/a`. As I said, there's a lot better ways to go about what you're doing, but I tried to stay focused on doing it the-way-you-were-trying.)*

Comment: Very well explained. Can we create an `eval` function which combines to-set-path for first part and to-word for subsequent parts?

Comment: I am also finding it difficult to adjust your code if var1 and var2 are "numbers" 5 and 10 (not strings). The keyword `to-string` creates an error when put in compose part.

Comment: @rnso EVAL can't be built in userspace in Red even in theory, because it would be "variadic", and it does not support that.  **eval :add** would consume two subsequent arguments (meaning EVAL had to act as arity 2), while **eval quote x:** would only consume one subsequent argument (a contradictory definition of EVAL at arity 1).  But even if you have variadics--[Ren-C does](https://trello.com/c/Y17CEywN/131-extremely-flexible-varargs-variadic-functions-with)--writing EVAL yourself would still be a major pain, like reimplementing the Rebol evaluator in Rebol.

Comment: @rnso I've modified the example to show you a place you can put TO-STRING.  Now your generated code block has three elements: a SET-PATH! and two WORD!s.  I will again reiterate I only explained this to try and tell you mechanically what was going wrong... and maybe the understanding will benefit you... but I will leave it to others and the [Red gitter.im](https://gitter.im/red) or something to talk about better ways; I do not speak for Red, nor do I work at all with the GUI dialect.

Comment: *(I would say there is "no reason Red couldn't add EVAL as a native"...however, from experience I will say it's not as trivial to add into an evaluator as it seems, especially if you're concerned about efficiency.  There's a lot of GC concerns about holding an additional cell for the evaluative product, paying for the initialization and maintenance of that cell, none of which is free...and trying to take shortcuts without breaking things like `eval eval eval...` can be challenging.  It's harder than it looks to write an EVAL that's both rigorous and efficient.)*

Answer (score 5):

This doesn't directly answer your question, though seems to address the problem you're facing. It uses the `face/extra` field to associate the fields to your value list:

```
namelist: [var1 var2]
var1: 5
var2: 10

process: function [][
    foreach face lay/pane [
        if find namelist face/extra [
            face/text: form get to word! face/extra
        ]
    ]
]

lay: layout [ 
    text "Values to appear here: "
    field "a" extra 'var1
    field "b" extra 'var2

    button "Click" [process]
]

view lay
```

The only wrinkles are: it applies `get` to the words as they are set in the View spec—they need to be within the same context as the values you're working on, and—you can't get a `lit-word!` so have to change it `to word!` before getting.

Another approach if you want to contain your values in a map:

```
values: #(foo: 5 bar: 10)

process: function [container [object!]][
    foreach face container/pane [
        if find values face/extra [
            face/text: form select values face/extra
        ]
    ]
]

view [ 
    text "Values to appear here: "
    field "a" extra 'foo
    field "b" extra 'bar

    button "Click" [process face/parent]
]
```

Answer (score 3):

## Step 1: refactor

Here is your code reformatted and `print` (1) statements added:

```
namelist: ["var1" "var2"]
var1: 5
var2: 10

process: [
    print "process: start"      ; (1)
    repeat i length? namelist [
        (to-set-path compose rejoin [namelist/:i "f/text"] (to-word namelist/:i))
    ]
    print "process: end"        ; (1)
]

lay: layout [ 
    text "Values to appear here: "
    var1f: field "a"
    var2f: field "b"

    button "Click" [do process]
]

view lay
```

When I run this in the *console* and press "Click", it gives the following:

```
process: start
process: end
```

So I know at least the button works

## Step 2: debug with `print`

Now I can focus, moving `print` inside the code block:

```
process: [
    repeat i length? namelist [
        print (
            to-set-path compose rejoin [
                namelist/:i "f/text"
            ] (to-word namelist/:i)
        )
    ]
]
```

Almost immediately I can see what's wrong here :

```
var1    ; expecting `var1f` here
var2    ;
```

## Step 3: we need to go deeper with `probe`

### Aside

Now, before I proceed further, notice that this code doesn't access 
anything inside the view block (*because it doesn't work!*).
But the nice thing here is you could ignore this and come back to it later.

*What you need is a way to access `var1f/text` programmatically*

Keeping that in mind, here is a better way to phrase this question:

### Step 3a: how to dynamically create `objects` with different names and set values to them?

`var1f/text: 5`

(given the code in step 2)

Now, I reach a conundrum here. This would probably be best asked as a different,  simpler question.

I decided to continue assuming you accomplished this (there's another answer too)

#### Note

The important thing to take home in this step is the `datatype` *Red view* uses and what you're working with is the same thing: red `object`s.
There is no difference (all are instances of a simple face object)

## Step 4: you're done! Or are you?

So you're able to create the gui you want for your work and you're done!
Right?

But then you ask yourself, is this the best way to do it?
What if you want to [add some more of this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46280562/getting-strings-from-a-list-into-vid-in-red-language?rq=1), or [something else entirely](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46261922/gui-elements-from-a-function-not-being-displayed-in-red-language)?

1. You have [read the official gui docs](https://doc.red-lang.org/en/gui.html) especially the part about [view engine](https://doc.red-lang.org/en/view.html#_the_face_tree)
2. You've looked at examples of [vid](https://github.com/red/red/blob/master/tests/vid.red#L8) and [adding view `face` objects manually](https://github.com/red/red/blob/master/tests/view-test.red#L878)
3. You've looked at the repo on github for [sample code and small apps](https://github.com/red/code/tree/master/Showcase)
4. You've even tried the old, but stable [rebol2](http://www.rebol.com/downloads.html)

But you still don't get it? Don't despair, this is normal.
A lot of stuff have names that are conceptually similar to what you are familiar in other languages but are different in subtle ways which tends to make them really different.
In the end tho, a lot is simpler than you'd think but stranger(having deeper implications)

## tl;dr

- Separate your view code from the rest so it's easier to debug
- Use `print`, `probe` and `dump-face` to debug